# Hide a tab in the TabHost in Android

Tags: android, tabs, visibility

```
if( ......)
    {


        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //to hide the first tab in the TabHost

    }
```

Is there anything wrong with this code ? The application crashes when I add this code inside the onCreate() method..
Any idea ?

My LogCat :

```
05-31 22:03:38.471: E/AndroidRuntime(598): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 05-31 22:03:38.471: E/AndroidRuntime(598): at swayam.dev.mushtouch.MushTouchActivity.setVisibilityControls(MushTouchActivity.j‌​ava:75) 05-31 22:03:38.471: E/AndroidRuntime(598): at swayam.dev.mushtouch.MushTouchActivity.onCreate(MushTouchActivity.java:220) 05-31 22:03:38.471: E/AndroidRuntime(598): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047) 05-31 22:03:38.471: E/AndroidRuntime(598): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
```

Also tried this code. Still keeps crashing.

```
getTabHost().getTabWidget().removeViewAt(0);
```

Comment: Not to be too obvious, but if you chance your subject line and tags to *mention what language or development environment you're asking about* you'll get answers.

Comment: Well, I had tagged it as "Android". Anyway, I changed the subject too after you said.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? Also, are you referencing the TabHost in code? If not, that is your problem.

Comment: @wdziemia What do you mean by referencing the TabHost ? 
tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost); This??

Comment: 05-31 22:03:38.471: E/AndroidRuntime(598): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-31 22:03:38.471: E/AndroidRuntime(598):  at swayam.dev.mushtouch.MushTouchActivity.setVisibilityControls(MushTouchActivity.java:75)
05-31 22:03:38.471: E/AndroidRuntime(598):  at swayam.dev.mushtouch.MushTouchActivity.onCreate(MushTouchActivity.java:220)
05-31 22:03:38.471: E/AndroidRuntime(598):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-31 22:03:38.471: E/AndroidRuntime(598):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)

Comment: @swayam view my answer below, hopefully that is the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My response is going to be too long so ill put it in an answer.

So far you have

```
TabHost  tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

You are getting a NullPointerException, meaning that whenever you are using that line of code, you are trying to change something that doesn't exist on screen, or possibly something off screen.

Check your Import statement for R.

Below your package statement you should have the following:

```
import your.package.R;
```

and not

```
import android.R;
```

Once that is fixed, when you reference your tab host, use the following:

```
TabHost  tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
```

If that doesnt work, make sure the tabhost is actually on the screen and that your not in a seperate activity.

Comment: This is the code for my TabHost the XML.                       <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">                      SO if I change the java code to R.id.tabhost, then it displays an error in the java code saying that the resource was not found. Also I tried changing the id of the TabHost in the XML to @+id/tabhost instead of @android:id/tabhost, but that causes other RuntimeExceptions saying that the name of the tabhost should be abdroid.R.id.tabhost.

Comment: Are you able to name is something else, like  @+id/tabhost1? then in code use R.id.tabhost1?

Comment: No nothing else seems to be working. If i give anything else, then the app force closes even before starting.

Comment: Well, I fixed it! Works like a charm now. Your code was great. Thanks for the help @ wdziemia

Comment: @swayam not a problem! Glad that was the problem, If you could mark it as the answer, i would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: not a problem for me either given the amount of help you provided. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you wanna hide Tab you should use:

**getChildTabViewAt()** instead of **getChildAt()**

so your code should looks like this:

```
  tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: it works fine for me so maybe there is some other problem. The stack trace could be helpfull :)

Comment: I am using a Toast at that same position and it works fine. But, as soon as I replace the Toast with this code, the app crashes.

Comment: did you set any TabSpec for your TabHost object?

Comment: TabHost.TabSpec spec = getTabHost().newTabSpec("tag1");

  spec.setContent(R.id.control);
  spec.setIndicator("Control", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.control));
  getTabHost().addTab(spec);

Comment: Working great for me, my tab content extends LinearLayout and I adding them via `mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("trasy").setIndicator("Trasy", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.drogo)).setContent(R.id.tracklist));`