# Add tab bar in xml file

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-tabhost

I have already created xml file and completed my project

Now i want to add bottom tab bar in my xml  file

Here my xml file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@drawable/main_bg" 
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"

>
<!-- Logo -->
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dip" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_bar" android:id="@+id/rel_jobDesc">

 <!--   <Button android:id="@+id/option"
         style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
        android:background="@drawable/skills"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:text=""
         ></Button> 
         -->

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"   android:id="@+id/txt_SEARCH_TITLE"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Job Search" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="20dip"
        android:textColor="#fff"></TextView>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnAboutus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  android:background="@drawable/draw"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:text="About Us"
         ></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/option"
        android:background="@drawable/hamburger"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         />

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/l1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rel_jobDesc" >

   <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@+id/logo"

   android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

   android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp" >


 <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_marginTop="55dip" android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dip">


<!--JOB DESCRIPTION -->
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txt_JOB_DESCRIPTION"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip" android:text="Job Description:"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
     android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="14dip" android:textColor="#000000"
    ></TextView>
    <EditText
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/edit_JOB_DESCRIPTION"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_JOB_DESCRIPTION"
    android:maxLines="1" 
     android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
    ></EditText>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txt_JDESCRIPTION"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dip" android:text="(Job title, industry,  keywords)"
    android:textSize="12dip" android:textColor="#4a596e"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edit_JOB_DESCRIPTION"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"></TextView>
<!-- -->

<!--LOCATION -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_JOB_LOCATION"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_JDESCRIPTION"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_SEARCH"
    android:text="Location:          "
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
 </TextView>

<EditText
android:id="@+id/edit_JOB_LOCATION"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edit_JOB_DESCRIPTION"
android:layout_below="@+id/txt_JDESCRIPTION"
android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
android:maxLines="1"
android:singleLine="true" >
 </EditText>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txt_JLOCATION"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dip" android:text="(City, State, Zip)"
    android:textSize="12dip" android:textColor="#4a596e"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edit_JOB_LOCATION"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"></TextView>
<!-- -->


<!-- JOB ID -->
<!-- -->



<!-- SEARCH BUTTON -->

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_SEARCH"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_JLOCATION"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dip"
    android:background="@drawable/draw"
    android:text=" Search " >
 </Button>
<!-- -->

</RelativeLayout>

  </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Please suggest me how we can add bottom tab bar in my xml file

Any help is Appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Check out my answer and try accordingly.

Comment: If you like to learn about this more see this link http://androidexample.com/Tab_Layout_%7C_TabBar_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=103&aaid=125

Comment: i want to check flag value if flag is true then change tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add like this-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TabHost
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="5dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

And in above code `android:layout_alignParentBottom=”true”` is used to align it to bottom.

In activity class-

```
    Intent intent;

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, FirstActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("First").setIndicator("First")
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SecondActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second").setIndicator("Second")
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ThirdActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third").setIndicator("Third")
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, FourthActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Fourth").setIndicator("Fourth")
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Comment: Increase or decrease height in **TabWidget** according to your requirement.

Comment: And like i place it below **btn_SEARCH**. you can also change attribute id.

Comment: and how we can access in my class and add home,search, myprofile button and handle click listener

Comment: I think with the help of above tutorial example you able to add home, search and other things.

Comment: Thanks for provide a link and i created a tab bar but when i click a Login button but tab bar added in login page and added a tab bar in next page

Comment: you want tab bar only in one page?

Comment: Its upto you add only those tabs you required using tabHost.addTab(spec);

Comment: yes i added but problem is tab bar added a previous page and when i click on tab bar then activity not changed

Comment: I dont know is it posible to remove previous page and i think for this you have to create new tab bar in different activtiy with different tabs. Let me see if i find any easy solution.

Comment: I've found this. Please check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837133/hide-a-tab-in-the-tabhost-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` for the `TabWidget` ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Tab host to get tab bar in your app.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:tabStripEnabled="false" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0" />
</LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

This to add tabhost at bottom , this wat you want i think.
Accept answer if this wat you want.
If you have any query , ping me.